# Order speed up - IB Python API

Tags: python, algorithmic-trading, interactive-brokers

I am building an automated trading strategy using the IB Python API. For the strategy to work well, **quick execution of the order is key**. First, the market price (so far only delayed) is queried and then the order is placed.

Code that I found for doing this uses several `time.sleep()` for allowing time to connect to the server which significantly slows down the order execution. I tried to decrease the sleeping times but this often led to the order not being executed. For example, the one-second `time.sleep()` in the delayed market price query is really slowing down order execution but decreasing it to e.g., 0.5 seconds, often leads to no price being found.

Is there any way that I can get **market price data** and **execute an order much more quickly**, ideally in under a second combined?

Also, is there a way of **combing** both the **market price** and **order execution query** in one query?

```
class IBapi(EWrapper, EClient):
    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def tickPrice(self, reqId, tickType, price, attrib):
        if tickType == 67 and reqId == 1:
            print('The current ask price is: ', price)
        global price_value
        price_value = price


def run_loop():
    app.run()

app = IBapi()
app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

# Start the socket in a thread
api_thread = threading.Thread(target=run_loop, daemon=True)
api_thread.start()

time.sleep(0.05)  # Sleep interval to allow time for connection to server

# Create contract object
contract = Contract()
contract.symbol = 'DAI'
contract.secType = 'STK'
contract.exchange = 'SMART'
contract.currency = 'EUR'

app.reqMarketDataType(3)

# Request Market Data
app.reqMktData(1, contract, '', False, False, [])

time.sleep(1)  # Sleep interval to allow time for incoming price data
app.disconnect()


class TestApp(EWrapper, EClient):

    def __init__(self):
        EClient.__init__(self, self)

    def error(self, reqId, errorCode, errorString):
        print("Error: ", reqId, " ", errorCode, " ", errorString)

    def nextValidId(self, orderId):
        self.nextOrderId = orderId
        self.start()

    def orderStatus(self, orderId, status, filled, remaining, avgFillPrice, permId, parentId, lastFillPrice, clientId,
                    whyHeld, mktCapPrice):
        print('OrderStatus. Id: ', orderId, 'Status: ', status, 'Filled: ', filled, 'Remaining: ', remaining,
              'LastFillPrice: ', lastFillPrice)

    def openOrder(self, orderId, contract, order, orderState):
        print('openOrder id:', orderId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, '@', contract.exchange, ':', order.action,
              order.orderType, order.totalQuantity, orderState.status)

    def execDetails(self, reqId, contract, execution):
        print('Order Executed: ', reqId, contract.symbol, contract.secType, contract.currency, execution.execId,
              execution.orderId, execution.shares, execution.lastLiquidity)

    def start(self):
        contract = Contract()
        contract.symbol = 'DAI'
        contract.secType = 'STK'
        contract.exchange = 'SMART'
        contract.currency = "EUR"
        contract.primaryExchange = "SMART"

        order = Order()
        order.action = "Buy"
        order.totalQuantity = 1 
        order.orderType =  "MKT"

        self.placeOrder(self.nextOrderId, contract, order)

    def stop(self):
        self.done = True
        self.disconnect()

def main():
    app = TestApp()
    app.nextOrderId = 1
    app.connect('127.0.0.1', 7497, 123)

    Timer(0.1, app.stop).start()
    app.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: There should never be a sleep.  1st, make a flow chart of how you want the program to work, like which steps follow which event.  eg, wake up -> connect to IB -> ask for data -> if price > $n order = buy, else order = sell -> order filled -> profit! -> disconnect.  2nd, program it without sleeps.

Comment: Sleep is not in any way a valid way to do this except for edge cases in the API. When you connect, request for ID to verify connection. A basic order placement with a reqMktData request for last price takes less than a second.

Comment: Thanks for your input @misantroop Do you have any code suggestions or links where this is done how you described? I am new to programming and don't exactly understand how this should be done, to be honest.